# Convert Number (decimal format) to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a column CPTIME with the data type decimal(6,0). Current value looks like 165750. I need it to be in TIME format 16:57:50. Is there a way to do that? I have seen somewhat similar questions asked, but that was with decimal hours/minutes (ie. 16.57 as 16:57), which does not apply here.

Comment: Sorry MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to CHAR, then add the colons and finally convert it back to TIME, like this:

```
SELECT (STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(135 AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
```

In the case you have fewer than 6 digits the '000000' concatenation will fill in zeroes and then we pick the 6 rightmost digits.

Comment: I get the following error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Here is the code: ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(CAST([CPTIME] AS CHAR(6)), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS TIME(0)) AS prdTime

Comment: Also, it should be noted that 12:01:35 would show up as 000135, which sql changes to 135

Comment: Change the first CAST to TRY_CAST and check if some rows converted and some didn't.

Comment: (0 rows affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'prdTime', table 'USOds.dbo.formattedManufacturingData'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `RIGHT(REPLACE('000000$d', '$d', [CPTIME]), 6)` should have better luck than a cast to `CHAR(6)`.

Comment: Yep, when you have fewer than 6 numbers things go wrong. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Jeroen, that worked when I added it to what kirchner said.